# Camera2 preview not working sometimes

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am using given link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic to make a new Camera2 for android version 5.0. Camera is working fine for me but sometimes preview does not set properly. I am sharing the images of camera preview below.
[image]

And second images is
[image]

please help me to short out the issue.

Note* How i can implement the Front and back camera open feature.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.